# SQL to delete subset entries

Tags: sql, subset, sql-delete

Imagine a table which has one entry with "**I pledge allegiance to the Flag of the United States.**",
and another entry with "**I pledge allegiance**"

Looking for the SQL to delete from the same table the shorter entry which is a subset of the longer entry.

I have this, but it is not working:

```
DELETE FROM mytable T1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT id FROM mytable T2 WHERE T2.Column1 like '%T1.Column1%')
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `like '%' || T2.Column1 || '%'`

Comment: `'%T2.Column1%'` is a *string literal* Have you tried your SQL Statement as a *select* to ensure it's identifying the correct row? It will of course return no rows

Comment: What [tag:rdbms] are you using?

Comment: jarlh -> no luck. Mureinik -> "mysql / MariaDb"

Comment: % wildcard matches zero-to-many chars, so every row will match itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use SELF JOIN for this case in next way:

```
DELETE T1.*
FROM mytable T1
JOIN mytable T2 ON T2.col1 like CONCAT('%', T1.col1, '%')
WHERE T1.id <> T2.id;
```

You can test this approach here:
https://sqlize.online/sql/mysql80/f88299d89532e9c6b3a251b071a8a541/

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
DELETE mytable
WHERE id in (
    SELECT t1.id
    FROM mytable t1
    JOIN mytable t2
        ON t1.column1 like '%' || t2.column1 || '%'
        AND LENGTH(t1.column1) < LENGTH(t2.column1)
)
```